# Could not find function "%>%" during CMD check

Tags: r, dplyr, package

I wrote an R package, which is based on `dplyr`. When I run the CMD check, an error pops up when evaluating the @examples.

```
could not find function "%>%"
Calls: Rresult
Execution halted
```

I have added `dplyr` in the description file, and the package works well when I run the examples myself. I don't know where the problem is.

Here is part of my description file:

```
Imports:
stats,
utils,
dplyr
```

As a matter of fact, during CMD check, some notes on `no visible binding for global variable` also appeared, which are related to `dplyr` package. For instance

```
Rresult: no visible global function definition for ‘group_by’
Undefined global functions or variables:
group_by
```

I used following code to remove the notes:

```
group_by <- filter_at <- "%>%" <- NULL
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Use `@ImportFrom` I think and import it from `magrittr`. Currently installing updates so spellings may be wrong.

Comment: Can you add the `DESCRIPTION` file?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be related to the tag [tag:cmd] , please adjust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the script that contains the function(unless you imported the entire dplyr).

```
@importFrom magrittr "%>%"
```

If you intend to use `dplyr` functions maybe explicitly call them like:

```
dplyr::group_by
dplyr::filter_at
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. @NelsonGon

Comment: I assume you're using `roxygen2` and `devtools`

Comment: Could you edit to say exactly where the notes were? I can't seem to get the purpose of this block: `group_by <- filter_at <- "%>%" <- NULL`

Comment: Check if the edit helps! because it seems to me you set the `pipe` to NULL

Comment: @ NelsonGon, thanks a lot for your help. With your script, I have found the problem. One of my dependency package `xcms` happens to have several same function names as `dplyr`. therefore some functions in `dplyr` have been replaced.